# "pod update" doesn't update to latest version

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

Here is my podfile I use in the project:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'MONActivityIndicatorView'
pod 'NYXImagesKit'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Countly'
```

The problem is that cocoapods 0.39 is updating AFNetworking to version 2.5.4 which is wrong. The latest version is 2.6.3 Also facebook SDK updating to 4.4 (latest is 4.8) etc.

I tried to delete Pods folder and .lock file but doesn't help

Also tried to clean the cocoapods cache but didn't help:

```
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ pod cache clean --all
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.5.4)
Installing Bolts (1.2.0)
Installing Countly (15.06.01)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.4.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.4.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.4.0)
Installing GoogleMaps (1.10.1)
Installing MONActivityIndicatorView (0.0.3)
Installing MagicalRecord (2.3.0)
Installing NYXImagesKit (2.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `myproject.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 9 dependencies from the Podfile and 10 total pods installed.
```

Comment: is your cocoa pods up to date?

Comment: yes. I updated cocoapods to version 0.39.0 as described above

Comment: Maybe try to remove , '~> 2.0' from AFNetworking line? and remove force-use of frameworks?

Comment: Make sure the `podspec` version info is correct, and that version points to the correct tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling of cocoapods solved the problem:

```
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
Password:
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Setup completed
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ cd ~/myproject/
MACMINI:myproject myusername$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking 2.6.3 (was 2.5.4)
Installing Bolts 1.5.0 (was 1.2.0)
Using Countly (15.06.01)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit 4.8.0 (was 4.4.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit 4.8.0 (was 4.4.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit 4.8.0 (was 4.4.0)
Installing GoogleMaps 1.10.5 (was 1.10.1)
Using MONActivityIndicatorView (0.0.3)
Using MagicalRecord (2.3.0)
Using NYXImagesKit (2.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 9 dependencies from the Podfile and 10 total pods installed.
```

Comment: This solution is overkill. The problem is likely a dependency within the Podfile that must be upgraded first.

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 24):

In my case, Neon wouldn't update for me.  It turns out it was because of the deployment target.

Changed 
`platform :ios, '8.0'`
to
`platform :ios, '10.0'`

And update worked normally.

Comment: Correct answer. I searched a lot, tried using several methods and this guy saved my time finally.

Comment: this is perfect solution! thanks Bojacob

Answer (score 13):

One of the reasons CocoaPods won't pick up the latest version of the pod could be another dependency that required an earlier version.

For example, suppose the latest version of PodA is 2.6 and you have this in your Podfile:

```
pod 'PodA', '~> 2.0'
pod 'PodB'
```

Unbeknown to you, PodB has the following dependency:
"PodA": "~> 2.5.4"

When CocoaPods tries to satisfy the dependencies, it will reject version 2.6 of PodA because it fails to satisfy the stronger dependency constraint on PodB.

One way to troubleshoot this is to ask CocoaPods to print the internal dependency graph debugging information by setting the following environment variable prior to running "pod update"

```
export MOLINILLO_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: For anyone stuck here figuring out which dep it is, try forcing one of the Pods to its latest version, such as `pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '> 8.6.0'` and running `pod update`. If it's unable to satisfy the dep using your version it should tell you *which* pod caused that. In my case it was `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` wanting a super old version of Firestore. I fixed it by hardcoding it to the latest beta `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.6.0-beta'`

Answer (score 6):

Installing latest cocoapods worked for me.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a new pod and it get me the latest

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.6.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `AfnetworkingPodFic.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

Try clearing the cache of Cocoapods

you can find how to from below

> https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Didn't help me. Updated topic

Comment: @Sergio I am getting the latest one see my updated answer

Comment: @Sergio try deleting the files too as mentioned in the link above

Answer (score 0):

Clean the pods cache in below paths and do pod install again.

~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/

~/.cocoapods/repos/ibm-cocoapods-specs

Answer (score -1):

$ pod update

in terminal  type this command, call update all pod to new version

Comment: Its not working for me

Answer (score -3):

Please update your CocoaPods like below:

```
myComputer:desiredFolder Test$ pod update
```