# Google Login with SFSafariViewController api in IOS with obj c

Tags: objective-c, safari, xcode8, google-signin, sfsafariviewcontroller

I was usgin google login api and everything was working just fine. But google has stopped accepting login requests from webviews (google error : disallowed_useragent) and if I send the user to safari to login then apple rejects my build with a suggestion(Use Sf Safari View Controller API) but I can not find any documentation for using google login with SF Safari Veiw Controller api.

Below is my code which I am using for google login which is working fine only if google and apple dont have issue with that:

```
GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;
signIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;
signIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;

signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
signIn.delegate   = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Below is my code which I have used to add SF safari View Controller to my app :

```
static NSURL *url = nil;
if(url == nil) {
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://13facts.info"];
}
SFSafariViewController *svc = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] 
initWithURL:url];
svc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So basiclly I know how to use SF Safari View Controller and I also know how to use google login but I don't know how to use both of them to make both google and apple happy so I can upload my working build of app to app store.

Any help is really appreciated.

I am using Objective c , XCODE Version 8.3.2 (8E2002).

Comment: Did you find any solution.

Comment: Not yet. Still digging deep without any documentation.

Comment: Actually you have to pass the link to Google Login in the `url`. I tried this and it's working.

Comment: How will passing simply the google login url will start the auth process?

Comment: I have this in one of my projects, will post an answer as soon as I find some time.

Comment: sure, waiting for the response soon.

Comment: How were you using UIWebView earlier? Post code if possible.

Comment: Its already in GIDSignIn Library :  signIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting you, you said you sent the user to Safari and then Apple rejected your build? How did you open Safari (code)?

Comment: Also, looks like you are using the older version of Google SDK since the properties `allowsSignInWithBrowser `, `allowsSignInWithWebView ` does not exist in the newer SDK. I would suggest updating you library, which will save you from all the hassle of `SFSarariViewController`

Comment: Well I added the sign in Liberary wit " pod 'Google/SignIn' " and also done pod update this mean I am using the latest version of the Google SignIn SDK. Answering your previous question , with " allowsSignInWithBrowser = ture" we can shift the auth process to browser instead of WebView.

Comment: The fact that you are able to use `allowsSignInWithBrowser` indicates your SignIn library is not updated. I would suggest reinstalling your pods.

Comment: Tried updating it Using pod update. It shows that library is up to date. If you may suggest me some other way to update ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893621/pod-update-doesnt-update-to-latest-version