# 'Cocoa Pod' can not download latest version (7.9.0) of 'GoogleMobileAds'

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods, admob

I have the GoogleMobileAds 'version 7.8.0'. Which ask me to update the latest version (7.9.0). I am trying to update from terminal

```
pod update

pod repo update

pod install --repo-update
```

But no one can update to the version 7.9.0. Which always show 'version 7.8.1'

So, how can I update to latest version? Can I download manually from where?

//If I want to download the latest version directly then google catches me the following link. 
    https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download

which is very oldest version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["pod update" doesn't update to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893621/pod-update-doesnt-update-to-latest-version)

Comment: last version is 7.8.0 , how you get 7.8.1 ? https://cocoapods.org/?q=GoogleMobileAds

Comment: latest version 7.9.0

Comment: are you using any GIT(github/bitbucket/tfs/xxx) to store your source code? Then it's related to that source repository. I faced the similar issue. I can suggest you to solve the issue.

Comment: no, I don't use bitbucket. source code is in my Mac book from it'd creation time

Answer (score 1):

You should be using 
`pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.9.1'`
rather than the `GoogleMobileAds` pod.

Comment: I use cocoa pod from several years. I know necessary command for terminal of cocoa pod. this is not issue of cocoa pod. Its a problem of Google admob sdk for cocoa pod version. So, strait forward solution will not work. I need a person who faced this problem and find a solution.

Comment: You did not give that info in your original question. Now that I know more about what you've tried, I went back and compared my results with yours and updated my answer.